# failed to clone repo by using command "git svn clone -s svn+ssh://repo_url"

Tags: git-svn

Initialization is done but then gives following error

```
Authorization failed: generic failure at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 1928
```

Answer (score 1):

Your hostname is missing in

```
   cat /etc/hosts
```

Edit file /etc/hosts and add

```
   127.0.0.1 hostname
```